# How to apply a function to rows of a SciPy CSR sparse matrix?

Tags: matrix, scipy

I have a CSR matrix of counts (X_ngrams). I would like to build a sparse log-odds matrix by taking the log of the quotient of each entry and the sum across the row. Here is my best shot:

```
log_odds = X_ngrams.asfptype()   # convert the counts to floats
row_sums = log_odds.sum(axis=1)  # sum up each row
log_odds.log1p()                 # take log of each element
for ii in xrange(row_sums.shape[0]):
    log_odds[ii,:].__add__(math.log(row_sums[ii,0]))
```

But that gives an error:

```
NotImplementedError: adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported
```

So, my question is: how do I modify the contents of a CSR? I only want to modify the elements that are present.

Other approaches would also be welcome. The basic problem is to modify a CSR based on the sum across the columns for each row for the elements that exist.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can tell, one cannot apply an arbitrary function for elementwise calculation on a CSR sparse matrix. Instead, you can create a new sparse matrix with the same structure and just run the calculation across the sparse data. Here is sample code that shows how to calculate the log() of the ratio of each element to the sum across the columns on each row:

```
X_ngrams.sort_indices()    # *MUST* have indices sorted for this to work!
row_sums =   np.squeeze(np.asarray(X_ngrams.sum(axis=1),dtype=np.float64))
rows,cols = X_ngrams.nonzero()
data = np.array( [ math.log(x/row_sums[rows[ii]]) for ii,x in   enumerate(X_ngrams.data)] )
new_odds = csr_matrix((data,X_ngrams.indices,X_ngrams.indptr),shape=X_ngrams.shape)
```

Here is a sample of the results, printing the first element of each row in both matrices:

```
          row_sum   Xngrams new_odds
[ 0][1439] 1063       20    -3.973118
[ 1][  13] 1677       18    -4.534390
[ 2][1439] 5323       68    -4.360285
[ 3][1439] 983        15    -4.182559
```

This is *not* fast, but I suppose it is good enough. The sample X_ngrams data set has 2,596,855 non-zero elements with a shape = (2257, 202262) and the creation of the new matrix takes 10.5s on my 5 year old macbook pro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`csr_matrix.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html) method to get the arrays of indices of nonzero elements.